# The API’s like Vision, Speech & Video intelligence use out of GCloud Infrastructure

Tags: gcloud, infrastructure, vision-api

The API’s like Vision, Speech & Video intelligence to use it in any web application, is it mandate to enrol for google cloud infrastructure?

Answer (score 0):

"enrol for google cloud infrastructure" - Yes you need to create a project on [google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com) with your gmail ID. 
Google is giving USD300 credit with your first project. 
[image]

However you don't need to start a compute engine to use speech recognition services. 
You will have to create buckets in google storage to upload long audio sequences in FLAC/PCM format.